# Intl PHP module in Wamp

Tags: php, apache, module, wamp, intl

Took out an app from my linux system and set it up on Wamp right now.
The app loads the Intl module from PHP, but the locale class doesn't work.
The SO settings are all right.
Debbuging

```
$get_locale = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
var_dump($get_locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $get_locale);
$locale_info = localeconv();
var_dump($locale_info);
```

I got:

```
 C:\wamp64\www\mysite\index.php:8:
array (size=18)
  'decimal_point' => string '.' (length=1)
  'thousands_sep' => string '' (length=0)
  'int_curr_symbol' => string '' (length=0)
  'currency_symbol' => string '' (length=0)
  'mon_decimal_point' => string '' (length=0)
  'mon_thousands_sep' => string '' (length=0)
  'positive_sign' => string '' (length=0)
  'negative_sign' => string '' (length=0)
  'int_frac_digits' => int 127
  'frac_digits' => int 127
  'p_cs_precedes' => int 127
  'p_sep_by_space' => int 127
  'n_cs_precedes' => int 127
  'n_sep_by_space' => int 127
  'p_sign_posn' => int 127
  'n_sign_posn' => int 127
  'grouping' =>
    array (size=0)
      empty
  'mon_grouping' =>
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

In addition, the Wamp reports a Warning:

> Warning: There is Wampserver path (c:/wamp64)
> into Windows PATH environnement variable: (C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.2.0)
> Warning: It seems that a PHP installation is declared in the environment variable PATH
> C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.2.0
> Wampserver does not use, modify or require the PATH environment variable.
> Using a PATH on Wampserver or PHP version
> may be detrimental to the proper functioning of Wampserver.

...but there are not envvars in the path.

Any insights are well come.

To get the locale information, but i got an empty array.

Comment: `setlocale()` and `localeconv()` are not part of the INTL extension, they are part of PHP. They perform a similar function but not as robust as INTL. However, it is likely that `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` is either empty or only has a language and not a country code. That would prevent most of the locale configuration from being filled as it has no idea what to fill it with (how do you get the currency without knowing the country?).